# Wordpress - Put a variable in php _e

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm using wordpress for one of my websites and the theme that I'm using has a metro-styled tiles slider.

Upon hover on a tile, I see this string "more". I checked the slider config for this type of slider and found that php _e is being used to get this string.

```
<div class="box box-1">
                        <a href="<?php echo $slide['slide_url']?>" ><img src="<?php echo $slide['slide_src']?>" width="306" height="391" alt="" /><span><?php _e('more','tfac');?></span>
```

Is it possible to change this to a variable through php echo or something? I have configured the slider settings to accept a custom value through the variable $slide_title.

```
array('name' => 'Slide Title',
                        'desc' => 'Change hover text here',
                        'id' => 'slide_title',
                        'value' => '',
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'divider' => true),
```

But despite replacing the php _e line with php echo $slide_title, I still see 'More' on hover.

I checked the theme's PO file and found this -

```
 #: E:\wamp1\wamp\www\mvibes.md\wp-content\themes\mvibes-parent/theme_config/extensions/slider/designs/gallery/template.php:8
 #: E:\wamp1\wamp\www\mvibes.md\wp-content\themes\mvibes-parent/theme_config/extensions/slider/designs/gallery/template.php:12
 msgid "more"
 msgstr ""
```

What do I do?

Comment: Have you checked if there's any css rule defining `:hover` to include `content('more')`? If you've _actually_ removed the `_e` call, then it will no longer be called. Are you sure you've uploaded?

Comment: Nothing in CSS about it. 

I changed the <?php _e('more','tfac');?> line with <?php echo $slide['slide_title']?> between <span> tag. Still it gives me that 'More' on hover instead of returning the value in slide_title. 

Of course uploaded it.